# Configure SQLServer 2000 Win7

Tags: windows, sql-server, firewall, remote-access

I've got `SQL Server 2000` running on `Win7`. There's no management tools so I wonder how do I configure/interact with the server. Main purpose for me is to enable remote connections. I know how to do this with `SQL Server 2008/Win7` but not with `SQL Server 2000`?

Is `1433` a default port for `SQL Server 2000`?

Is it possible to allow port thru `Windows Firewall` with `Win7 Home Basic`?

Thanks!

Comment: Do we want to know why you are trying to run an ancient SQL Server on a non-server OS? o.O You could turn off Windows Firewall to see if that is causing the issue.

Comment: @helicera - this is a site for PRO sysadmins, who wouldn't consider such a pointless and stupid configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2000 allowa remote connections by default; Windows Firewall is what's probably stopping remote clients from connecting.

The default port for SQL Server 2000 (as for any SQL Server version) is TCP 1433.